# How to delete a bot's own message in node.js botbuilder?

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot

I know that you can use `connector.delete(address, callback)` to delete a message, but is there a way to get the address for a message that I created by `session.send()`?

Visualization:

1. Person sends message A
2. Bot responds with message B
3. Person sends another message
4. How can the bot delete message B?

Note that `session.message.address` points to message A

Comment: What channel(s) are you using?

Comment: The default connector and all these channels offered in Bot Registration itself.

Comment: you will only be able to use the delete command in channels that offer the feature to delete old messages, for example, slack offers this.

Comment: to answer you question, the `address` parameter is an instance of [`IAddress`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/5cf71c742f27d89e9dbc4076f850122bd6edac11/Node/calling/src/interfaces.d.ts#L91)  I'm not 100% sure but you may need to use [`IChatConnectorAddress`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/2048133f22882155f742c1d6006288f2a8a6d75e/Node/core/src/bots/ChatConnector.ts#L84).  You would just have to save the information somehow from the previous message.

Comment: So how can I save this information after sending this message? i.e. How can I catch the address of the message that I just sent?

Comment: are you just trying to delete any random message or a specific message?

Comment: A specific message that the client has sent.

Comment: Do you have some sort of datastore that you can trigger activity data to be stored in so you can later access the the activity ID?

Comment: Yes. But I don't know how to get the address first?

Comment: From the original activity that was sent.  The activity will have an Id.